# uploading videos to Instagram from PC

Tags: bluestacks

Ok i keep it simple

I edited a video and placed a picture in the first frame (for cover) now i want to upload it via my PC not my phone. I tried Nox , Bluestacks , MEmu , Droid4X , Andy and KOPLAYER but all of them crash when you try to share a video.

The Only Program that work was Grambler but you **can't** set the first frame as cover.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you would like to upload it via your computer? If there is no particular reason you could easily just upload the video file to a file sharing site (Google Drive, Dropbox, etc) and then download it on your phone and upload it from there. I doubt there is a way to upload it from your computer, you could try Genymotion but it may not work.

Comment: my phone is old but got a new laptop :) found a way. I just add an extra second (not one frame) at the beginning of the video with my picture. import it to Grambler , select the cover. select the start of the video after that 1 second.